# using a class's variable in another class function

Tags: c++, qt, class

i have classes like this

```
class A : public QDialog
{
A(QWidget *parent);
static map<int,QString> dataa;
};

class B : public QThread
{
public void run();
}

class C : public QDialog
{
public void abc();
}
```

**Defination of classes**

```
void B::run()
{
in this function,i am using __dataa__ as __dataa.insert__which is defined initially in A class as public.
}

void C::abc()
{
in this function also,i am using __dataa__ as __dataa.find__ and dataa.end__ which is defined initially in A class as public.
}
```

Now please help me how can i use that variable dataa in the other two classes B and C.somewhere i seen we have to declare it as static and use it in the B and C class as A::data but its not working and giving error.

these three classes are initialized as

```
int main()
{
A window;
B datathread;
datathread.start
//B is Qthread inherited and A,C are QDialog inherited
}
```

class C is initialized from class A by clicking a pushbutton on it and opening its dialog in a new window.
i guess this time i wont be blamed for not clearly formulating my question.please on gods name help me as i am stuck over this from long time.a big thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: "its not working and giving error" - What is the error? Also in general, you shouldn't try to access data like that from one class to another, especially from threads. Instead, inject the data from class A to class B.

Comment: undefined reference to A::dataa
and other one is
more undefined reference to A::dataa
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

i have no idea of that inject method.can u edit my code and paste it in your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined reference to A::dataa

You need to define it in A's .cpp file. Say:

```
std::map<int, QString> A::dataa;
```

Also to make sure this is accessible elsewhere there are two options:

- declare this map object in the `public` section of A class
- or have a copy of this object returned via a function like @Jeeva suggests.

Now, to access this variable in other units, you would first include the header file for A class.

```
#include "A.h" //or something similar..
```

And to access it:

```
void B::run() //and similar with C::run(..)
{
    A::dataa //do something with it ..
}
```

Comment: do i have to declare it as static or just like map<int,QStrin> dataa;

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with QT but i guess this might help. If you want to use class'A data in class b or c there are three options

1. Inherit class B and C from class A if the relationship is meaningfull
2. Create instance of class A inside class B & C (Containment)
3. Access the class A's data through a public member function of class A like

   `public:`

   ```
      map<int, QString> GetData()
      {
        return dataa;
      }
   ```

Comment: in third one i will declare this function in a as friend function.its ok.but wont it give error because function is friend but not dataa so how can i use it in other class.
and second one sounds most appropriate can you please edit by question and post it in your answer to show me a general way of doing it?