# Only defined inside a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Meny
{
public:
    void Meny2()
    {
        cout << "Welcome " << Name << LastName;
    }
};

class Kund
{
public:
    string  Name, LastName, personnummer;

    void LoggaIn()
    {
        cout << "Please enter your full name: " << endl;
        cin >> Name >> LastName;
        cout << "Please enter your social security number: " << endl;
        cin >> personnummer;
    }
};
```

So currently `cout << "Welcome " << Name << LastName;` wont work because `Name` and `LastName` are undefined in the `Meny` class, is there a way to make them be defined even though they are defined in another class?

Comment: Instanciate an object?

Comment: different classes are different scopes. you have to have access to have those variable in scope, e.g. by accessing an instance of class that contains them. It's basic rule of language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using a class's variable in another class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407005/using-a-classs-variable-in-another-class-function)

Comment: Pass in the user to the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` and `LastName` are not properties of `Meny`. They are properties of `Kund`. So these properties are not accessible. You have to somehow make that accessible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Kund
{
public:
    string  Name, LastName, personnummer;

    void LoggaIn()
    {
        cout << "Please enter your full name: " << endl;
        cin >> Name >> LastName;
        cout << "Please enter your social security number: " << endl;
        cin >> personnummer;
    }
};

class Meny
{
public:
    void Meny2(const Kund& k) const
    {
        cout << "Welcome " << k.Name << k.LastName;
    }
};
```

or subclass

```
class Meny: public Kund
{
public:
    void Meny2() const
    {
        cout << "Welcome " << Name << LastName;
    }
};
```

or template

```
template <typename T>
class Meny: public T
{
public:
    void Meny2() const
    {
        cout << "Welcome " << Name << LastName;
    }
};
```

or use template in function

```
class Meny
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Meny2(const T& k) const
    {
        cout << "Welcome " << k.Name << k.LastName;
    }
};
```

Comment: When I call Meny2 in the first one what would be in the ( )?

Comment: For the first one it will be a reference to a `Kund` object. e.g. `Kund k; Meny m; m.meny2(k);`

Comment: Maybe you answered my question... but like if I have an int main() and inside of that I want to call the function, I would do

Comment: Meny MenyObjekt; MenyObjekt.Meny2(); but it says to few arguments in function call in the ()

Comment: You instantiate `Kund k;` and `Meny m;` first inside `main()` and then call `m.meny2(k)`. Call `MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObject)` in your case.

Comment: It says "const <error-type> &k". Im also getting a lot of errors :(

Comment: Note subclassing should only be used if it naturally makes sense to say that every `Meny` really is a `Kund`. Don't use it just to get access to variables, functions, etc. if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Declare `Kund` before `Meny`. Because when you are referring to the type `Kund` it should be already defined.

Comment: @aschepler  yes right. However I don't know meaning of these words `Kund` or `Meny`.

Comment: Here the link is working. Nothing much. I have  declared Kund before anything.